# Using Process.Start in C#

Tags: c#, python, .net, uwp

I want to start python aplication from C# so I use method Process. After I ran it and click the button I get

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file
>   specified

In either case. What's wrong?

```
 int counter = 0;         

    private void button1_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        TextBox1.Text = counter.ToString(); 
        //Process.Start("Python.exe", "C:\\Users\\kamil\\source\\PythonApplication2\\PythonApplication2.py");
        Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");
    }
```

Comment: You have not given the full path to IExplore.exe or Python.exe and these paths are not set in the PATH environment variable

Comment: Hi Kamil, can you confirm if one of the below solutions answered your question, if yes, kindly mark as resolved by clicking the green tickbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be the full path of python.exe and I explore.exe. You can specify full path for them. Even a path can be added to PATH env variable. If a path is specified in PATH environment vatriable you don't need to specify the full path. You can change it like this:

```
var old = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)
var new = old + @"Full path, here you don't need to escape double quotes."
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", new, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)
```

It is a good practice to include path inside @"" here special characters don't need escaping.